# Is there a term for a cocktail made of equal proportions of its ingredients?

Tags: cocktails, terminology

Is there a name for the class of cocktails where all ingredients are in equal proportions? For example, if I were to make a menu of things like a Corpse Reviver, Paper Plane, Last Word, etc. I'd like to title the menu with that term. I think "Perfect Cocktail" is fitting but I know that's for equal parts sweet and dry vermouth.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a custom cocktail of equal proportions and simply naming it something to your liking... I am just guessing but something like naming a method for making cocktails with equal proportions is so general, and so rare, that the name would likely never stick.

Comment: How about: “Equilateral Libations”?

Comment: "*Is there a term for a cocktail made of equal proportions of its ingredients?*"  STRONG!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there a term for a cocktail made of equal proportions of its ingredients?**

There seems to be no known terminology for a cocktail made with equal proportions of ingredients!

However that can not stop one from coining such a phrase. I would suggest something like an **”Equal portioned cocktails!”**

Do not call it an [**Equalizer**](https://www.johnniewalker.com/en-us/whisky-cocktails/equalizer/) because that is already a valid cocktail.

If you make a cocktail of four equal portioned ingredients you could call it a **4 by 4 cocktail!**

Take the pound cake as an example, called in French a **”quatre-quart”** (four-quarter).

> The pound cake is aptly named. Historically, the total ingredients are equivalent to one pound. In French, it is called **"quatre-quart"** because it **consists of four ingredients of equal weight: one quarter of flour, one quarter of butter, one quarter of sugar and one quarter of eggs.** It is an old recipe that gives a slightly dense cake, ideal for tea and trifles. You could even add grated lemon or orange zest. - [Pound Cake](https://www.ricardocuisine.com/en/recipes/442-pound-cake)

Comment: Perhaps more accurately, the French likely renamed it because they have no reference to imperial measurements - they use the metric system which doesn't include the pound!

Comment: Personally I'd go for "Equal portioned potion".